# How to add wordpress plugin update available code

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have been googling for a while now but can find anywhere or a good resource which explain how to add functionality to your plugin that you see when a plugin is ready for a update.

Can someone explain how to add this functionality to a wp plugin, so you get the following when updating the plugin

> There is a new version of User Access Manager available. View version
>   1.2.2 details or update automatically.

??? can someone point me in the right direction please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line is build-in wordpress code. To enable it, you have to use [wordpress code plugin repository](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/about/).

Comment: ok so how do i enable it my plugin is on the wordpress svn repository and i am committing new updates but it doesnt show???

Comment: wordpress only check for updated plugins once a day. So, you have to be patience.

Comment: ahh i cant be patient ;) ok thankyou so if i commit and change the version from 0.1 to say 0.2 this will then show the update 2morrow? With plugin update

Comment: yup, you can either wait, or search for the plugin in plugin finder to see if it is already updated. But. Don't download it, because it will current version and you will not see the update message by tomorrow.